# How I can get the tuples in tables N to N in laravel?

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-4

I have the following data model

[image]

A technician can have many services and a service can have many technical

**Tecnico Model**

```
class Tecnico extends Eloquent{
protected $table = 'Tecnico';
protected $fillable = array('Auth_Token');

public function servicios(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Servicio', 'Servicio_Tecnico', 'idTecnico', 'idServicio');
}
}
```

**Servicio Model**

```
class Servicio extends Eloquent{
protected $table  = 'Servicio';

public function detalleServicio(){
    return $this->hasOne('Detalle_Servicio', 'idDetalle_Servicio');
}

public function tecnicos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tecnico', 'Servicio_Tecnico', 'idServicio', 'idTecnico');
}
}
```

**I'm trying to get all the services of a particular technician according to the "auth_token"**

**ServicioController**

```
class ServicioController extends BaseController{

public function obtenerServicios($auth){

    if($auth != ''){
        $tecnico = DB::table('Tecnico')->where('Auth_Token',$auth)->first();
        if($tecnico != null){
            $servicio = $tecnico->servicios;
            $response = Response::json($tecnico);
            return $response;

        }else{
            $array = array('Error' => 'NotAuthorizedError', 'Code' => '403');
            $response = Response::json($array);
            return $response;
        }
    }else{
        $array = array('Error' => 'InvalidArgumentError', 'Code' => '403');
        $response = Response::json($array);
        return $response;
    }

}

}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('servicio/{auth}', array('uses' => 'ServicioController@obtenerServicios'));
```

**Error**

[image]

How I can get all that technical services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: it's best to use the Eloquent model to query instead of DB::table.

Eg:

```
$tecnico = Tecnico::with('servicio')->where('Auth_Token',$auth)->firstOrFail();
```

The DB query builder doesn't know the Eloquent relationships. Eloquent only knows the Query builder.

And second: don't pass access tokens in the URI. Not in a segment and not in the query string. Use headers for that.

Eg:

```
Route::get('servicio', 'ServicioController@obtenerServicios');

class ServicioController extends BaseController {

    public function obtenerServicios() {
        // strip the "Bearer " part.
        $token = substr(Request::header('Authorization'), 0, 7);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, in applying its first review appeared the following error ``Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Servicio.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `Servicio`.*, `Servicio_Tecnico`.`Tecnico_idTecnico` as `pivot_Tecnico_idTecnico`, `Servicio_Tecnico`.`Servicio_idServicio` as `pivot_Servicio_idServicio` from `Servicio` inner join `Servicio_Tecnico` on `Servicio`.`id` = `Servicio_Tecnico`.`Servicio_idServicio` where `Servicio_Tecnico`.`Tecnico_idTecnico` in ())``

Comment: Because the default primary key column is `id`. I can see in your schema you chose `idServicio` instead. Add a `protected $primaryKey = 'idServicio';` to your `class Servicio`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Eloquent to get Eloquent results like Model::find() etc. (DB::table... will return stdObject, that's the error you get), and correct these relations:

```
// class Tecnico
public function servicios(){
  // the keys are wrong:
  // return $this->belongsToMany('Servicio', 'Servicio_Tecnico', 'idTecnico', 'idServicio');

  // it should be like this:
  return $this->belongsToMany('Servicio', 'Servicio_Tecnico', 'Tecnico_idTecnico', 'Servicio_idServicio');
}

// class Servicio
public function tecnicos(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tecnico', 'Servicio_Tecnico', 'Servicio_idServicio', 'Tecnico_idTecnico');
}
```